# Help in a Join query

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT game_ratingstblx245v.game_id,avg( game_ratingstblx245v.rating ) 
         as avg_rating,
       count(DISTINCT game_ratingstblx245v.userid) 
          as count,
       game_data.name,
       game_data.id ,
       avg(game_ratings.critic_rating),count(DISTINCT game_ratings.critic) 
         as cr_count
FROM game_data 
LEFT JOIN game_ratingstblx245v ON game_ratingstblx245v.game_id = game_data.id 
LEFT JOIN game_ratings         ON game_ratings.game_id = game_data.id 
WHERE game_data.release_date < NOW() 
GROUP BY game_ratingstblx245v.game_id 
ORDER BY game_data.release_date DESC,
         game_data.name
```

I am currenty using this query to extract values from 3 tables 

game_data - id(foreign key), name, release_date \games info

game_ratings - game_id(foreign key),critic , rating \critic rating

 game_ratingstblx245v - game_id(foreign key), rating, userid \user rating

What I want to do with this query is select all id's from table game_data order by release_date descending, then check the avg rating from table game_ratings and game_ratingsblx245v corresponding to individual id's(if games have not been rated the result should return null from fields of the latter two tables)..Now the problem I am facing here is the result is not coming out as expected(some games which have not been rated are showing up while others are not), can you guys check my query and tell me where am i wrong if so...Thanks

Comment: shouldn't you be grouping by game_data.game_id ?

Comment: This whamps man, I just overlooked it...Thanks that did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `game_ratingstblx245v.game_id` column in your GROUP BY, since it could be NULL when there are no ratings for a given game id.  Use `game_data.id` instead.

Here's how I would write the query:

```
SELECT g.id, g.name,
       AVG( x.rating ) AS avg_user_rating,
       COUNT( DISTINCT x.userid ) AS user_count,
       AVG( r.critic_rating ) AS avg_critic_rating, 
       COUNT( DISTINCT r.critic ) AS critic_count
FROM game_data g
LEFT JOIN game_ratingstblx245v x ON (x.game_id = g.id)
LEFT JOIN game_ratings r         ON (r.game_id = g.id)
WHERE g.release_date < NOW() 
GROUP BY g.id 
ORDER BY g.release_date DESC, g.name;
```

Note that although this query produces a Cartesian product between `x` and `r`, it doesn't affect the calculation of the average ratings.  Just be aware in the future that if you were doing `SUM()` or `COUNT()`, the calculations could be exaggerated by an unintended Cartesian product.

Comment: Thanks Bill for the extra info you're always the first one to help me out....On a side note I don't understand what do you mean by cartesian product?

Comment: A Cartesian product is one where every row in one table is combined with every row in the second table.  Say you have 10 matching rows in the first table, and 12 matching rows in the second table.  If no condition restricts the matching conditions between these two, you'll end up with 120 rows in the result.  What this means in a query like yours is that rows from each ratings table get repeated unintentionally.  This would be a problem if you were doing COUNT() or SUM().

Comment: To see the Cartesian product in action, try your query without the GROUP BY, and show the `rating` columns instead of calculating the AVG().  You'll see a lot of repeated rows.

Comment: Yes you are right i was making this mistake earlier and the return values for count were giving me weird values which were much higher than real values but I fixed it later on....